# Applying GARCH to Panel Data

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, paneldata

I have a panel consisting of some quantity - say earnings/cash flows/or something similar.

I am interested in forecasting the volatility that is inherent to that respective measure. In a single time series setting, I would estimate a GARCH model to do this. There is plenty of literature on this and it is pretty straight forward to implement.

However, how do I do this in a panel setting? A very naive approach would be to just take the average across the cross-section and each period, which in turn would yield a single time series. However, I would thereby completely ignore cross-sectional variation.

Comment: Great question! Here are a couple of references that might be useful (but I have not checked them out carefully): [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016517650900370X) and [2](http://www.ipe.ro/rjef/rjef4_18/rjef4_2018p71-84.pdf).